# How to pass password in bash without prompting to ask to type in?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, amazon-ec2, terminal

What I wanted to do is:
run a bash script from my local terminal, to run a jar file in an EC2 instance.
But in order to run the script, I'll have to first log in with .pem credentials, and then do `su admin` and type admin password to gain run access. The command I've figured out so far is like this:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_credentials.pem -t ${EC2IP} 'su admin' "ADMIN_PASSWORD" 'cd /tmp' 'java -jar my-program.jar'
```

But it's still prompting me to type the ADMIN_PASSWORD, and then after that, my terminal will be logged into that EC2 machine, which is not what I wanted, I just want to finish all of the commands, and then continue with another EC2 instance.

How could I achieve that please?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: This might help: [Allow user1 to “su - user2” without password](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/113754/74329)

Comment: Why are you using `su` here at all? It's much easier to configure `sudo` for passwordless access, or configuring SSH to provide your private key direct access to the account you're trying to `su` to.

Comment: You seem to assume that the strings you paste are supplied as standard input to `ssh` but this is not at all the case. Maybe see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc

Answer (score 0):

there is no proper solution to your problem. Maybe you can change some security rules in `/etc/pam.d/su`. But I am not sure if and how.

I know why you cant use `ssh` in combination with `su`...
`su` is intended  to run on the server terminal, or with other words:
`su` needs the correct **TTY** to communicate with.

---

Passing a password to `su` also doesnt work.
Most programms that use a password have a option to put the passowrd in it,
 unfortunately `su` use promt only.

[A NOT recommended method would be this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command).

---

You could avoid using `su` by connecting via `ssh` and username admin,
or giving the rights to the user that you were using in the first place.

Hope this gets you going.

Comment: Not quite accurate that there exists no possible approach -- with `expect` for instance, one has an emulated TTY that can be scripted.

Comment: updated my post

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command)  <-- **not recommended**

Comment: Definitely agreed that expect is the Wrong Thing -- was just making a point that the original language  speaking in terms of *possibilities" was inaccurate.

Comment: oops, ok. edited my post again. thx for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

A.  Don't do this.  Use sudo instead.  You'll probably need to comment out the following line from /etc/sudoers on the target:

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

B.  Assuming that you're going to do this anyway, use expect to do it for you:  http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html

But, seriously, don't do it.